# How to take only max period respective values within range of partition

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark-sql

How to take only max period respective values within range of partition

Comment: Hi, could you clarify why for 20180310 both device B and C were included in the sum and for 20180317 excluded 20180310    B? Could you number the input rows and show which rows contributed to each sum?

Comment: @alexeipab : I need to consider sum of max(period)  of respective device in the range of 4. yes sure.

Comment: what do you mean by "in range of 4"?

Comment: This question is lacking sample data and expected output, as well as a few explanation on the context.